# QtableView set whole row as readonly

Tags: c++, qt, row, readonly, qtableview

I am having problems setting the whole row of a `QTableView` to read only. When I use `setEnabled` method it only makes the first column readonly. Here is an example, I am adding a new row to the table and trying to make the whole row readonly:

```
void CItemsMenu::addSlave(const quint8 addr, const QString& uniqId, const QString& userString)
{
    // create new item
    QStandardItem* item = new QStandardItem(m_columnLabels.size()); // size is 3

    // make item readonly
    item->setEditable(false); // this makes only the 1st column readonly

    // append new item
    mp_itemsModel->appendRow(item);
    int row = mp_itemsModel->rowCount() - 1;

    // slave address
    mp_itemsModel->setData(mp_itemsModel->index(
                                 row, (int)itemsTableCol::slaveAddr, QModelIndex()), addr, Qt::EditRole);

    // unique ID
    mp_itemsModel->setData(mp_itemsModel->index(
                                 row, (int)itemsTableCol::uniqId, QModelIndex()), uniqId, Qt::EditRole);

    // user string
    mp_itemsModel->setData(mp_itemsModel->index(
                                 row, (int)itemsTableCol::userStr, QModelIndex()), userString, Qt::EditRole);
}
```

I would appreciate all help.

Edit: solution:

```
QList<QStandardItem*> itemsList;
for (int i = 0; i < m_columnLabels.size(); i++)
{
     itemsList.append(new QStandardItem(1));
     itemsList.last()->setEditable(false);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need one item per cell.

When you call:

```
mp_itemsModel->appendRow(item);
```

you only set the item for the first column. Quoting Qt documentation:

> When building a list or a tree that has only one column, this function
>   provides a convenient way to append a single new item.

When dealing with a QTableView you should be calling the overload of `appendRow()` that takes a `QList<QStandardItem *>`. Like this:

```
QList<QStandardItem *> list;
... // Fill list and set all items in the list to be read-only.
mp_itemsModel->appendRow(list);
```

Comment: But in this line `QStandardItem* item = new QStandardItem(m_columnLabels.size());` I create an item with 3 columns. How to make a list of it if it already is a sort of list?

Comment: @ŁukaszPrzeniosło That is not what you are doing. The prototype is `QStandardItem::QStandardItem(int rows, int columns = 1)`, so you are creating an item with `m_columnLabels.size()` rows and 1 column. Moreover, the documentation says "_Constructs an item with rows rows and columns columns of child items._" So the `rows` and `columns` number has nothing to do with how many row/column your item takes, but how many row/column your item children will have. This is only useful in QTreeView.

Comment: @ŁukaszPrzeniosło You should take a look at the documentation: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandarditemmodel.html#details

Comment: I see, but I still dont know how to set editable flag for each column of the row. How to get a list here, I only have 1 item. Could you please provide an example?